# compilation error with registers, c++14 and gcc

Tags: c++, c++14, gcc4.9

Below is the code which i am compiling with gcc 4.9 with flag -std=c++1y:

```
#include <stdio.h>
register unsigned long sp asm ("sp");
int main()
{
    printf("[%d] \n",((unsigned long)(sp) >= 5));
    return 0;
}
```

I got the error as "expected explicit address for register for '(sp)'". But, without c++1y flag, i am not getting the error.  I couldn't get any information on flags to suppress this  or c++14 feature which is showing this problem. Please anybody share your thoughts to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question.

Comment: `register` is only a hint and is deprecated. In C++17 it'll be removed. Don't use it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, 'register' used like this has a special meaning to [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html#Global-Register-Variables).  "Not using" the register keyword means not declaring a Register Variable. Of course using the stack pointer as a register variable seems like a really bad idea.  Comparing it to a constant also seems dubious.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: If this is a GCC extension being used then the question is not about the C++ language and ought to be updated to make that clear. In particular, no answer will be found in the C++ language standard.

Comment: I can't speak to why the OP tagged the question the way he did.  I will observe that without the `-std=c++1y` compiler flag, the error he is describing does not occur.

Comment: Just i suspected, that using brackets is  not allowed in c++14 standard, which gcc will implement. So, i mentioned c++ in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason (I do not know why), putting parentheses around the `sp` causes GCC to believe you want the address of the variable (which is impossible for a register variable), which seems like a bug to me, but may be some kind of intentional behaviour due to some weird part of the standard.

You also don't require the cast for your variable.

This code works with `-std=c++14`:

```
#include <cstdio>

register unsigned long sp asm ("sp");
int main()
{
        std::printf("[%d] \n", (sp >= 5));
        return 0;
}
```

Which will print `1` on my machine (since you're printing the truth value).

Comment: I think it's a holdover from C. In actual C++, the semantics of a variable declared `register` should be entirely indistinguishable from those of a variable declared without any storage class specifiers. Anyway, the "weird part of the standard" that causes this is, I bet, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion triggered by the `()` expression.

Comment: As an alternative, there's always `unsigned long long sp; asm("movq %%rsp, %0", "=rm"(sp));` (assumes x64). Although the `-std=c++1y` thing still makes the generated code ugly (the pointer thing elizafox was referring to).  Not sure why comparing the stack pointer to a constant makes sense either.

Comment: This is just the sample code where compilation error occurs. There is no usage of stack variable/constant with register in actual code.  i just added the code that cause compilation error only  with c++1y.